How to Delete and Truncate Everything on Drizzle (PostgreSQL)
I'm a bit surprised this isn't present in the Drizzle docs or, better yet, isn't a function out of the box with it, but how exactly do you delete and truncate everything?
I've tried many variations of what's on this Answer Overflow post but it doesn't seem to truncate things actually:
async function deleteEverything() {
  try {
    await db.delete(posts)
    await db.delete(users)

    const tableSchema = db._.schema
    if (!tableSchema) throw new Error("No table schema found")

    console.log("️  Emptying the entire database")

    const queries = Object.values(tableSchema).map(
      (table) => {
        console.log(` Preparing delete query for table: ${table.dbName}`)
        return sql.raw(/* sql */ `TRUNCATE TABLE ${table.dbName} CASCADE;`)
      },
    )

    console.log(" Sending delete queries...")

    await db.transaction(async (tx) => {
      await Promise.all(
        queries.map(async (query) => {
          if (query) await tx.execute(query)
        }),
      )
    })

    console.log("✅ Database emptied")
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}


Following @SvetoslavPetkov's tips, I've tried adding the following:
await db.transaction(async (tx) => {
  await tx.execute(sql.raw(/* sql */ `SELECT pg_resetxlog();`))
})

But apparently the pg_resetxlog function doesn't exist? (postgres (PostgreSQL) 14.11 (Homebrew))
PostgresError: function pg_resetxlog() does not exist
    at ErrorResponse (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/postgres@3.4.4/node_modules/postgres/src/connection.js:803:66)
    at handle (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/postgres@3.4.4/node_modules/postgres/src/connection.js:489:6)
    at Socket.data (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/postgres@3.4.4/node_modules/postgres/src/connection.js:330:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
    at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
    at TCP.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
  severity_local: 'ERROR',
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42883',
  hint: 'No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.',
  position: '8',
  file: 'parse_func.c',
  line: '636',
  routine: 'ParseFuncOrColumn'
}


Do you get any errors?, personally I wouldn't use Promise.all, for something like this, I would use for (const query of queries) { await tx.execute(query); }  Otherwise your executing X amount all at the same time, and this might cause deadlocks especially where relations are concerned.   Also do you only have tables in your schema, no views, etc, otherwise you might want to do table instanceof PgTable check first.

@Keith I didn't see any errors popping up when I was using this. Should we get deadlocks even after we've deleted all data with the db.delete(...) statements at the beginning of the function?

To be fair I'm not a pg expert, but is the problem just that the physical files don't reduce in size?.  If so yo might want to try VACUUM FULL after you have done the deletes.

I'm doing this just because it's annoying to delete all data but still have to deal with an ever increasing index.

delete posts and users leave records in the transaction log.
If you want to clear also the transaction log you can use pg_resetxlog. (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-pgresetxlog.html)
There are human readable logs which can only be deleted in the fyle system

@SvetoslavPetkov you mean I should probably create a db.transaction with sql.raw(/* sql */ \pg_resetxlog();`)` inside?

yes, you can try

@SvetoslavPetkov I've added an edit with the error that occurred from your pg_resetxlog suggestion.
